# How to get an element of a float list by index?

Tags: animation-nodes

How can i get a specific value of a float list by index?

for example: I have a list [3, 4.5, 89, 12]. In this list 3 is the ranked 1 value, 4.5 is ranked 2, 89 is ranked 3 and 12 is ranked 4. How to obtain a value in this list if I only know the rank of this value ?

Comment: so you want from [2, 4, 3, 1] become [1, 2, 3, 4]? i don't get it. Please add an understadable example of numbers. thanks.

Comment: Have you ever used animation nodes ?

Comment: would i ask if i haven't? by the way...you should be quick, because you have already 2 close votes because 2 people don't understand what you meant...just a hint. So you should improve your question instead of asking questions which are a bit weird....

Comment: Ok. To explain it clearer. I need a to transform integer number to numbers contained in a float list relative to their rank in this float list.

Comment: You should update your question, not add a comment. And an example would help a lot.

Comment: I don't know how to explain clearer that what I want to say. If you need more details, ask for it.

Comment: I need more details in why people don't understand my question to full update it.

Comment: As I said : add an example. I can understand if you are not good in writing English, but you should add a good example like I did: i have this list: [3.5, 5.6, 2.6, 1.5] result should be: [9,7,6,4]

Comment: for exemple: I have a list [3, 4.5, 89, 12]. In this list 3 is the ranked 1 value, 4.5 is ranked 2, 89 is ranked 3 and 12 is ranked 4. How to obtain a value in this list if I only know the rank of this value ? Do you understand this example?

Comment: use get list element, use index as your rank, then you get that value

Comment: like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKpDx.png

Comment: i corrected the question and vote to reopen again. I am happy lazare finally gave us an example.

Comment: You solved my question. Thank you Chris.

Comment: you are welcome. Please add examples next time in your questions so we have a chance to understand what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131077/discussion-between-chris-and-lazare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with this node setup:

[image]

I first created a float list (from your example).

With the "Get List element" node you can get any list element from a list by index.

The viewer shows the result.